# Match descriptions and copy/paste associated quantity

Tags: excel, vba

In Sheet 1, column A contains a list of product names and column B a list of quantities. The number of rows is variable and could be a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 15 (from row 62 to 76 - blank rows are automatically hidden). In Sheet 2, column A contains the same product list, but all 15 of them, ie Sheet 1 is a dynamic range and Sheet 2 is a static range. I am attempting to set up a VBA procedure whereby the macro will match the product in column A62 (Sheet 1) with column A4-18 (Sheet 2), copy the corresponding quantity from column B in Sheet 1 to column B in Sheet 2 and then move down the product list in Sheet 1, doing the same till it reaches the end of the dynamic range.

If anyone can assist or point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful. Many thanks.

Comment: If you don't have some other need to use VBA, you could probably achieve that result by just having a VLOOKUP formula in column B of Sheet2.

Comment: I could, but what I should have added was that I need to retain the ability for the user to manually enter those totals there too, for different reasons. By doing a simple lookup, they'd then be overwriting formulas.

Comment: A simple macro could then just paste formulae into Sheet2, which the users could overwrite if they wished to.  That would be no different to the macro pasting values into Sheet2, which the users could overwrite if they wished to.  I think `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B4:B18").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,_dynamicrangename_,2,False),""Not found"")"` would probably work.

Comment: That would be a fallback if all else fails, but it goes against the objective of the range on Sheet 2 being an input cell that is either populated by a direct input or from Sheet 1 where a formula was used to create a quantity on Sheet 2 or to populate it with any different quantity. In short, I want users to be able to adjust the quantities that are copied across and preferably not have to overwrite a formula to do so.

Comment: Your macro could use two commands then: `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B4:B18").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,dynamicrangename,2,False),""Not found"")"` followed by `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B4:B18").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B4:B18").Value`

Comment: Of course! I don't know why I didn't think of that. That'll work perfectly, thank you.